# How can I allow a user sudo/root on SFTP?

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, sftp

I've got a Hetzner Dedicated Root server, and would like to either allow the root user to access SFTP - Which doesn't work at the moment, I get this error:

```
Status:    Connecting to <IP>...
Response:    fzSftp started, protocol_version=8
Command:    open "root@<IP>" 22
Command:    Pass: **
Error:    Authentication failed.
Error:    Critical error: Could not connect to server
```

Or, I'd like a new secondary user with all permissions. At the moment I have a second user, but it cannot access/read/write all directories (`/etc/nginx/sites-available` specifically).

I used OVH before Hetzner and they had pre-configured root SFTP access. However, Hetzner's servers don't have this setup and I've been struggling.

So, to summarise: I'd like to use SFTP as a root/sudo user with unrestricted access to all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't - such a  mechanism for elevated privilege browsing as a non-root user doesn't exist in SFTP.

You would have to enable the `root` account and give whomever needs the elevated access direct access to that account instead, which for obvious security reasons (risk of bruteforcing the `root` account and risking someone gaining power over your system, for starters) is dangerous.

Comment: OVH allowed full unrestricted SFTP over the root login.

Comment: @BriskNode but that's OVH being stupid with their VPSes; default permissions and such, **and** you're using the `root` account directly.  (They actually intend for you to use that only temporarily and then harden up the system).  Just because OVH allows something doesn't mean it's not dangerous or a good security practice.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about this. I had a dedicated server on OVH with this but switched to Hetzner for more RAM for my budget. Is there a way to give another SFTP only user access to all files?

Comment: @BriskNode ACLs, but you should never give a non-root account total system access like that.

Comment: I'll probably remove access when I've done setting it up